# How to make grid view open a specific new page when clicked?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Could someone look at my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong. The code retrieves the ID from the position in the array, uses a switch statement, and changes the layout based on what is selected. Any suggestions? (It is not listed here, but the code has imported all proper classes and packages)

```
public class Newpage extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


      // get intent data
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // Selected image id
    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
 // based on position switches to its respective screen

    switch (position)
    {
   case 6:
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.layout.page1);
       this.setContentView(view);
       break;
   case 0:
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       view = (TextView) findViewById(R.layout.page2);
       this.setContentView(view);
       break;
   case 1:
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       view = (TextView) findViewById(R.layout.page3);
       this.setContentView(view);
       break;
   case 2:
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       view = (TextView) findViewById(R.layout.page4);
       this.setContentView(view);
       break;
   case 3:
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       view = (TextView) findViewById(R.layout.page5);
       this.setContentView(view);
       break;
   case 4:
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       view = (TextView) findViewById(R.layout.page6);
       this.setContentView(view);
       break;
   case 7:
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       view = (TextView) findViewById(R.layout.page7);
       this.setContentView(view);
       break;
    }



}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.layout.page1);
```

why did you do that?

Comment: So I could change the textview with each case?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to change the activity or the content of the textview? A textview is a component of an layout. You have to set the content of layout using setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout)  and if you want to change the content of the textView u first declare the text view TextView mytextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1); then u use mytextView.setText("here is a string");

Comment: I want to change to change the content, therein changing the page the app displays. Are you saying I should setcontenetview first and then add textview?